# Unable to fire a Multipart Request with RestAssured

Tags: rest-assured

I have been trying to send a multipart request using RestAssured v2.9.0, however it's always throwing errors.

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/my-url", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public void saveSomething(
            @RequestParam("form") MultipartFile formFields,
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
            @AuthenticationPrincipal ...
```

RestAssured call:

```
given().header(HEADER_NAME, HEADER_VALUE)
        .filter(new RequestLoggingFilter())
        .multiPart(getMutliPart("{//JSON FORM FIELDS}", "form", "application/json", "blob"))
        .multiPart(getMutliPart("Test-Content-In-File", "file", "text/plain", "Test.txt"))
        .when()
        .post("my-url");
```

Error message:

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'form' is not present
```

RestAssured Log:

```
Request method: POST
Request path:   http://localhost:50789/my-url
Proxy:          <none>
Request params: <none>
Query params:   <none>
Form params:    <none>
Path params:    <none>
Multiparts:     controlName=form, mimeType=application/json, charset=<none>, fileName=blob, content=[123, 345..blah blah]
                controlName=file, mimeType=text/plain, charset=<none>, fileName=Test.txt, content==[13, 34..blah blah]
Headers:        HEADER=VALUE
                Accept=*/*
                Content-Type=multipart/form-data
Cookies:        <none>
Body:           <none>
```

Apparently, `Request params` is blank and that's the reason for the error.

I have also tried sending a `MockMultipartFile` inside the `.parameters("form", mockMultipartFile)` but no luck.

I have referred to a lot of stuff online including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41124388/how-to-send-a-multipart-request-with-restassured), but the issue still exists. Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with this.

```
RequestSpecBuilder builder = new RequestSpecBuilder();
builder.addParam("form", "..form fields json");
builder.addParam("file", "..file");
RequestSpecification requestSpec = builder.build();

given().header(HEADER_NAME, HEADER_VALUE)
        .filter(new RequestLoggingFilter())
        .spec(requestSpec)
        .config(RestAssured.config().encoderConfig(encoderConfig().encodeContentTypeAs("application/json;charset=UTF-8", ContentType.JSON)))
        .when()
        .post("my-url");
```